# Testing a NUXT.js and Vue.js app with Jest. Getting '[vuex] module namespace not found in mapState()' and '[vuex] unknown action type'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vuex, nuxt.js

In spite of my understanding that NUXT does namespacing automatically. Because of this, I am unable to test or reference the store in any of my testing modules.  Can anyone give me a tip? Maybe where I can edit the namespacing property in a Nuxt app?

Here is the code below for the component, store, and the test.

ButtonComponent.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-btn @buttonClick v-model="value"></v-btn>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data: {
      return {
          value: 25
      }
  }
  methods: {
    buttonClick(event) {
      this.$store.dispatch('buttonComponent/setNewValue', valuePassedIn)
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

buttonComponent.spec.js:

```
import Component from '../../Component'
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import expect from 'expect'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(Vuetify)

describe('Component', () => {
  let store
  let vuetify
  let actions
  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
        actionClick: jest.fn()
    }
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      actions,
    })
    vuetify = new Vuetify()
  })



  it('method sends value to store when button is clicked', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Component, {
      store,
      localVue,
      vuetify,
    })
    wrapper.find('.v-btn').trigger('click')
    expect(actions.actionClick).toHaveBeenCalledWith('buttonComponent/setNewValue', 25)
  })
})
```

buttonComponent.js:

```
export const state = () => ({
  value: 0,
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_TO_NEW_VALUE(state, value) {
    state.value = value
  },
}

export const actions = {
  setNewValue({ commit }, value) {
    commit('SET_TO_NEW_VALUE', value)
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that I don't have to write it again here, I'll link you to an article I just posted that walks through the setup process to so you can test your Nuxt stores with Jest: https://medium.com/@brandonaaskov/how-to-test-nuxt-stores-with-jest-9a5d55d54b28

Comment: It takes about 5 seconds to run 1 test on my machine using the nuxt builder. A better option is to mock the nuxt store.

Comment: @ioan mocking behavior within your own codebase is a terrible idea. There should have been a better way to do this.