# How to unit test Vuex modules defined with vuex-module-decorators syntax in Nuxt, using vue-test-utils and Jest?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, unit-testing, nuxt.js, vuex

I cannot find an answer to this question anywhere.

I went through the official Nuxt documentation and through the  existing Stack Overflow and Github issue discussions.

Implementation of the AuthModule:

```
@Module({
  stateFactory: true,
  namespaced: true,
})
export default class AuthModule extends VuexModule {
  userData?: UserData | undefined = undefined;
  prevRouteList: Routes[] = [];
  error?: services.ICognitoError | undefined = undefined;
  isLoading = false;
  ...

  @VuexMutation
  setIsLoading(isLoading: boolean) {
    this.isLoading = isLoading;
  }
 
  ...

   @VuexAction({ rawError: true })
  async register(registerData: { email: string; password: string }): Promise<any> {
    this.context.commit('setIsLoading', true);
    this.context.commit('setError', undefined);
    this.context.commit('setInitiateRegistration', false);
    this.context.dispatch('setEmail', registerData.email);

    try {
      const { user } = await services.register(registerData.email, registerData.password);

      if (user) {
        this.context.dispatch('pushPrevRoute', Routes.emailVerification);
        this.context.commit('setInitiateRegistration', true);
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      this.context.commit('setError', error);
      this.context.commit('setInitiateRegistration', false);
    }

    this.context.commit('setIsLoading', false);
  }

  ...

  @MutationAction
  setEmail(email: string)  { ... }

  ... 

  get getEmail() {
    return this.email;
  }

  ... 

}
```

My `/store` directory contains only Vuex modules (like the example  AuthModule). There is no index.ts where I declare and instantiate the store. Also the modules are not dynamic.

So my questions are:

1. What is the correct pattern of writing unit tests for Nuxt Vuex modules, defined with [vuex-module-decorators](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators) synax, using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started) and [vue-test-utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/)?
2. How can I unit test VuexMutations, VuexActions, MutationActions, getters etc.?

I tried instantiating the AuthModule class inside the test file, but I can't get it to work.

```
describe('AuthModule', () => {
  const authModule = new AuthModule({...});

  it('test', () => {
   console.log(authModule);

   /* 
     AuthModule {
      actions: undefined,
      mutations: undefined,
      state: undefined,
      getters: undefined,
      namespaced: undefined,
      modules: undefined,
      userData: undefined,
      prevRouteList: [],
      error: undefined,
      isLoading: false,
      registrationInitiated: false,
      registrationConfirmed: false,
      forgotPasswordEmailSent: false,
      forgottenPasswordReset: false,
      email: '',
      maskedEmail: ''
    }*/
  });
```

I also tried the approach explained here:

https://medium.com/@brandonaaskov/how-to-test-nuxt-stores-with-jest-9a5d55d54b28

and here:

[Testing a NUXT.js and Vue.js app with Jest. Getting '[vuex] module namespace not found in mapState()' and '[vuex] unknown action type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60085863/testing-a-nuxt-js-and-vue-js-app-with-jest-getting-vuex-module-namespace-not)

Here's my setup based on the recommendations in those articles / links:

```
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  roots: [
    '<rootDir>/components',
    '<rootDir>/pages',
    '<rootDir>/middleware',
    '<rootDir>/layouts',
    '<rootDir>/services',
    '<rootDir>/store',
    '<rootDir>/utils',
  ],
  reporters: ['default', 'jest-sonar'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js', 'vue', 'json'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest-amcharts',
  },
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/components/**/*.vue',
    '<rootDir>/pages/**/*.vue',
    '<rootDir>/layouts/**/*.vue',
    '<rootDir>/middleware/**/*.ts',
    '<rootDir>/store/**/*.ts',
    '<rootDir>/mixins/**/*.ts',
    '<rootDir>/services/**/*.ts',
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!(@amcharts)\\/).+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$'],
  forceExit: !!process.env.CI,
};

// jest.setup.js

import { config } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { Nuxt, Builder } from 'nuxt';
import TsBuilder from '@nuxt/typescript-build';
import nuxtConfig from './nuxt.config';

config.stubs.nuxt = { template: '<div />' };
config.stubs['nuxt-link'] = { template: '<a><slot></slot></a>' };
config.mocks.$t = (msg) => msg;

const nuxtResetConfig = {
  loading: false,
  loadingIndicator: false,
  fetch: {
    client: false,
    server: false,
  },
  features: {
    store: true,
    layouts: false,
    meta: false,
    middleware: false,
    transitions: false,
    deprecations: false,
    validate: false,
    asyncData: false,
    fetch: false,
    clientOnline: false,
    clientPrefetch: false,
    clientUseUrl: false,
    componentAliases: false,
    componentClientOnly: false,
  },
  build: {
    indicator: false,
    terser: false,
  },
};

const nuxtBuildConfig = {
  ...nuxtConfig,
  ...nuxtResetConfig,
  dev: false,
  extensions: ['ts'],
  ssr: false,
  srcDir: nuxtConfig.srcDir,
  ignore: ['**/components/**/*', '**/layouts/**/*', '**/pages/**/*'],
};

const buildNuxt = async () => {
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(nuxtBuildConfig);
  await nuxt.moduleContainer.addModule(TsBuilder);

  try {
    await new Builder(nuxt).build();
    return nuxt;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = async () => {
  const nuxt = await buildNuxt();
  process.env.buildDir = nuxt.options.buildDir;
};


// jest.utils.js

import Vuex from 'vuex';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueFormulate from '@braid/vue-formulate';
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';

const createStore = (storeOptions = {}) => new Vuex.Store({ ...storeOptions });
const createRouter = () => new VueRouter({});

const setup = (storeOptions) => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.use(VueRouter);
  localVue.use(Vuex);
  localVue.use(VueFormulate);

  const store = createStore(storeOptions);
  const router = createRouter();
  return { store, router, localVue };
};

export const createNuxtStore = async () => {
  const storePath = `${process.env.buildDir}/store.js`;

  // console.log(storePath);
  const NuxtStoreFactory = await import(storePath);
  const nuxtStore = await NuxtStoreFactory.createStore();

  return { nuxtStore };
};

export const createTestBed =
  (component, componentOptions = {}, storeOptions = {}) =>
  (renderer = mount) => {
    const { localVue, store, router } = setup(storeOptions);

    return renderer(component, {
      store,
      router,
      localVue,
      ...componentOptions,
    });
  };

// auth.spec.js

import { createNuxtStore } from '@/jest.utils';

describe('AuthModule', () => {
  let store: any;

  beforeAll(() => {
    store = createNuxtStore();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    console.log(store);
  });
});
```

After I run this I get this error in the console:

```js
 RUNS  store/auth.spec.ts
node:internal/process/promises:245
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

ModuleNotFoundError: Cannot find module 'undefined/store.js' from 'jest.utils.js'
    at Resolver.resolveModule (/Users/ivan.spoljaric/Documents/.../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:306:11)
    at Resolver._getVirtualMockPath (/Users/ivan.spoljaric/Documents/.../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:445:14)
    at Resolver._getAbsolutePath (/Users/ivan.spoljaric/Documents/.../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:431:14)
    at Resolver.getModuleID (/Users/ivan.spoljaric/Documents/.../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:404:31)
    at Runtime._shouldMock (/Users/ivan.spoljaric/Documents/.../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1521:37)
    at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (/Users/ivan.spoljaric/Documents/.../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:916:16)
    at /Users/ivan.spoljaric/Documents/.../jest.utils.js:24:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at Object.createNuxtStore (/Users/ivan.spoljaric/Documents/.../jest.utils.js:24:28) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  hint: '',
  requireStack: undefined,
  siblingWithSimilarExtensionFound: false,
  moduleName: 'undefined/store.js',
  _originalMessage: "Cannot find module 'undefined/store.js' from 'jest.utils.js'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error I finally discovered the answer to my question.

If you are like me; only starting your journey with Vue, Nuxt & vuex-module-decorators and you get stuck tackling this exact same problem, I hope this little solo QA ping-pong finds you well!

My solution looks like this:

```
// auth.spec.ts

import Vuex, { Store } from 'vuex';
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';

import AuthModule, { IState } from './auth';

jest.mock('@/services');

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);

const storeOptions = {
  modules: {
    auth: AuthModule,
  },
};

const createStore = (storeOptions: any = {}): Store<{ auth: IState }> => new Vuex.Store({ ...storeOptions });

describe('AuthModule', () => {
  let store: Store<{ auth: IState }>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = createStore(storeOptions);
  });

  describe('mutations', () => {
    // ...

    it('auth/setIsLoading', () => {
      expect(store.state.auth.isLoading).toBe(false);
      store.commit('auth/setIsLoading', true);
      expect(store.state.auth.isLoading).toBe(true);
    });

    // ...
  });

  describe('actions', () => {
    // ...

    it('register success', async () => {
      const registerData = {
        email: 'dummy@email.com',
        password: 'dummy',
      };

      expect(store.state.auth.registrationInitiated).toBe(false);

      try {
        await store.dispatch('auth/register', registerData);
        expect(store.state.auth.registrationInitiated).toBe(true);
      } catch (error) {}
    });

    // ...
  });

  describe('mutation-actions', () => {
    // ...

    it('setEmail', async () => {
      const dummyEmail = 'dummy@email.com';

      expect(store.state.auth.email).toBe('');
      await store.dispatch('auth/setEmail', dummyEmail);
      expect(store.state.auth.email).toBe(dummyEmail);
    });

    // ...
  });

  describe('getters', () => {
    // ...

    it('auth/getError', () => {
      expect(store.state.auth.error).toBe(undefined);
      expect(store.getters['auth/getError']).toBe(undefined);

      (store.state.auth.error as any) = 'Demmo error';
      expect(store.getters['auth/getError']).toBe('Demmo error');
    });

    // ...
  });
});

// services/auth

export async function register(email: string, password: string, attr: any = {}): Promise<any> {
  try {
    return await Auth.signUp({
      username: email,
      password,
      attributes: {
        ...attr,
      },
    });
  } catch (err: any) {
    return Promise.reject(createError(err, 'register'));
  }
}

// createError is just a util method for formatting the error message and wiring to the correct i18n label

// services/__mock__/auth

import { createError } from '../auth';

export const register = (registerData: { email: string; password: string }) => {
  try {
    if (!registerData) {
      throw new Error('dummy error');
    }

    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve({ response: { user: registerData.email } }));
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(createError(err, 'register'));
  }
};

//
```

The most important thing to realise is that the [vuex-module-decorators](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators) class-based module behaves just like a [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) under the hood.

All of the vuex-module-decorators stuff is just syntactic sugar - a wrapper around the vue-class-component API.

To quote [the docs](https://championswimmer.in/vuex-module-decorators/pages/getting-started.html#define-a-module):

> In your store, you use the MyModule class itself as a module...The way
> we use the MyModule class is different from classical object-oriented
> programming and similar to how vue-class-component works. We use the
> class itself as module, not an object constructed by the class

Another thing to keep in mind is to use [createLocalVue](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/createlocalvue.html), which enables us to use Vue classes, plugins, components etc. without polluting the global Vue class.

Adding the Vuex plugin to `createLocalVue`:

`localVue.use(Vuex);`

The AuthModule class is declared as a Vuex (namespaced) module inside the Vuex.Store constructor (as per docs).

```
const storeOptions = {
  modules: {
    auth: AuthModule,
  },
};

const createStore = (storeOptions: any = {}): Store<{ auth: IState }> => new Vuex.Store({ ...storeOptions });
```

In the implementation above, AuthModule (incl. store, actions, mutations, getters...) is re-created for every test case with the help of the `beforeEach` hook (so we have a clean store for every test)

The rest is pretty straightforward. You can see how I tested each part of the AuthModule (actions, mutations, getters..)